# Why zero-field splitting acts like a energy barrier?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetism, quantum-spin

I'm trying to understand the magnetic anisotropy of single-molecule magnets. I know that spin states $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are degenerated and an unpaired electron could be in one of them. When a molecular system shows zero-field splitting $(H_{ZFS} = DS_z^2 + E(S_x^2 - S_y^2))$, the spin states split in doublets (for a half-integer spin system).

Applying an external magnetic field, the system is magnetized where all molecules are on $-m_S$ (for $D<0$). Removing the external magnetic field, the molecules of the system start to relax overcoming the energy barrier $U=(S^2 - 1/4)D$ through excited spin states.

The question is why is not possible to just flip the spin state from $-m_S$ to $+m_S$? Why it should overcome the barrier or do quantum tunneling?